# using egrep for regular expression check on String

Tags: pattern-matching, ksh, grep, sunos

I have to validate a String against a regular expression for a date format `YYYYMMddhhmmss`.

I have tested the below code:

```
temp=echo $file_timestamp | egrep '^(20)[0-9][0-9](0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123])([0-5])[0-9]([0-5])[0-9]$';
```

The following returns the content of `file_timestamp` if it satisfies the pattern, else returns `null` to the variable `temp`.

Is this code snippet optimized per unix standard?

Comment: please clarify your question - what do you mean by `validate my understanding`?

Comment: Wanted to know whether the code snippet is optimized and as per unix standard. Are there any other optimized approach for the above?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a unix standard that explicitly addresses your question.

Also standards, versus good working code are sometimes at odds (not that often).

I can think of at least 3 issues with code, even reg expressions, that as a developer I want to make are covered.

1. are the results correct? Only you can know this. Building your code as test-driven development isn't something that just java-people can do. Make a file with the range of inputs you think you should support, and make sure the output is working for all cases, AND if this is really a big project, have error messages showing what wasn't processed.
2. Is it maintainable? A block of comments detailing how you think the regular expression is working will be helpful to those that come after you, OR even for yourself 6 months from now, and you haven't looked at a reg-exp since.
3. Performance. Is there an alternate "phrasing" of the regular expression that still gives a correct answer, but "runs" faster?

Taking your reg-exp, I think I would have done it differently, given your definition. Note that this version is shorter, so by a very simple metric, it's easier to maintain.

```
temp=$(echo $file_timestamp \
| egrep '^20[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][1-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]$'
)
```

Unless you care to explain your use of `( .... )` grouping characters, I don't see any use for them.

(The only thing I can think of is that your specified format `YYYYMMddhhmmss` is more flexible than you indicate. You're not trying to match any format of date the user might put it, i.e. YYYYMdhms (when there is a leading zero for any of the element?. Beware, this is a path to madness and incorrect data going into your system! ;-)

Finally, you don't indicate how you use $temp in your validation. I think a much simpler way to validate an existing variable (and more flexible) is to use a case statement. Try

```
 case ${file_timestamp) in
     20[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][1-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9] )
       print -u2 -- "dbg: valid : file_timestamp=${file_timestamp}"
       # do other good stuff here
     ;;
     * )
       print -u2 -- "dbg:NOT valid : file_timestamp=${file_timestamp} "
       # do other error reporting or fixing here
     ;;
   esac
```

Now your avoiding extra processes for the $( ... ) and the `grep`.

If you need your grouping chars like `(2[0-9])`, then you'll have to use grep (sed, awk, etc) as ksh regexps don't support `()` grouping (I'm almost sure).

IHTH

Comment: Is there any inbuilt Unix function to test whether a date entered is a valid date or not. Through Regular Expression i can limit the date to the pattern but i am unable to restrict the user from giving certain values like e.g.30 Feb.

Comment: No, sorry, no inbuilt function for date validations. Linux versions of the date command can convert many input date formats to different output formats, but require specifying the expected format, (essentially a regular expression). You can of course chain multiple tests together and have a test for `30 Feb` as needed. So now I think I understand the intent of your original question. If you want to reject illegal date values, like `30 Feb`, the easiest thing to to use specfic reg-exp in the case statement above that will flag the error. They would go before the 'Good date regex`.

Comment: There are many questions here on S.O. already about converting and validating dates. you should search for `[linux] date convert` or `[linux] date validate`, substituting `[unix]` for `[linux]` if appropriate. If you find my answer has pointed you in the right direction to solving your problem, please accept it as a correct answer. Good luck.

Comment: I tried formatting using date -d , but i get "illegal option"

Comment: I am using SunOS. Do i have to install any patch?

Comment: The only way I know to get `-d $date` functionality, is from the GNU date utility, but You'll get a better answer posting a question at http://serverfault.com/ like "I need the GNU date functionality of `date -d ${date}` on my Sun OS ver XXX? server. What packages do I need to install? Or is there another way to get this functionality". (I'm not a sysadmin, so I only know vaguely about this stuff). Note that you'll likely require root access to have this installed. For your future questions, please add a tag for SunOS, as this greatly affects the usefulness of answers you will get. Good luck.